# EXC_BAD_ACCESS only when returning from scrolling all the way down in a UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios7

EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x71474b80)

This error appears when the user returns from scrolling all the way down in a nested UITableView. If I don't scroll to the bottom, the error doesn't happen.

maybe there is a deallocation problem as suggested by

[UIViewTableController: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" When Scrolling Up/Down Past the Max Position of the Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329800/uiviewtablecontroller-exc-bad-access-when-scrolling-up-down-past-the-max-posi)

My code is:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TroncalesInfo";

    TroncalesViewCell *cell = [[TroncalesViewCell alloc]init];
    cell = [tabla dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.IDTroncal = [nombresTroncales objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setCellAtributes:indexPath db:dataBase];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little hack I always use. I don't know exactly why it works, but give it a try ;).

Insert this in the viewWillDisappear of your viewController:

> tabla.delegate = nil;

Comment: You are right Aaron. Sorry for not explaining it. It seems to me that the viewController or the table's delegate is getting deallocated while the view is being scrolled (scrollViewDidScroll?). As the UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, forcing it to be nil cancel all calls to the UITableViewDelegate protocol, including the scrollViewDidScroll. Please correct me if I am wrong Aaron.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the source of your problem, but this code:

```
TroncalesViewCell *cell = [[TroncalesViewCell alloc]init];
cell = [tabla dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

should be closer to this:

```
TroncalesViewCell *cell = [tabla dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[TroncalesViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

I think your existing code might return a `nil` cell, which would throw an exception.  Right now you are pointlessly initializing a cell and then throwing it away and replacing it with another one.

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TroncalesInfo";
    
    TroncalesViewCell *cell = [tabla dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[TroncalesViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.IDTroncal = [nombresTroncales objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setCellAtributes:indexPath db:dataBase];
    
    return cell;
}          did this, but still not working !!!

Comment: with objective-C enable zombie objects checked :D

[TroncalesViewController scrollViewDidScroll:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x18462d40

Comment: Looks like your tableview is getting deallocated while it's still visible.  Do you have a strong reference to it?

Answer (score 0):

From the crash log, it seems that the delegate of TroncalesViewController has been realloced when it should not be. You can check to make sure TroncalesViewController's delegate is still alive when you scroll the view.